# How can it possible to parse array from string come from server as json string?

Tags: json, swift

Hi I am new in swift 3 development. I got following data from server. Swift 3 treat following data as string. I need to convert then array and store them to database later. The data was produced by Gson().toJson(List). I don't know how to convert string to array and loop through arrays.

```
"[{"trxDate":"May7","trxNo":"1234,"trxP":500,"id1":"123","id2":"345"}]"
```

if the data contains like below then how to parse them?

```
"[{"trxDate":"May7","trxNo":"1234,"trxP":500,"id1":"123","id2":"345"},{"trxDate":"May8","trxNo":"3455,"trxP":530,"id1":"123","id2":"345"}]"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `JSONSerialization` to deserialize the string to a collection type. Look into the *Related* column.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work.

```
let str = "[{\"trxDate\":\"May7\",\"trxNo\":\"1234\",\"trxP\":500,\"id1\":\"123\",\"id2\":\"345\"},{\"trxDate\":\"May8\",\"trxNo\":\"3455\",\"trxP\":530,\"id1\":\"123\",\"id2\":\"345\"}]"

if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {

    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> {

        guard let array = json else { return }

        print(array)

    } else {

        print("Not valid JSON")
    }
}
```

First of all, your string was missing a few quote marks making it an incorrect JSON format.

For the compiler to recognise the whole JSON string as a string, you need to add backslashes before the quote marks, as shown in the str above.

This is what is printed in the console.

```
[["id1": 123, "trxDate": May7, "trxNo": 1234, "id2": 345, "trxP": 500], ["id1": 123, "trxDate": May8, "trxNo": 3455, "id2": 345, "trxP": 530]]
```

This is what is printed without casting json to array.

```
(
        {
        id1 = 123;
        id2 = 345;
        trxDate = May7;
        trxNo = 1234;
        trxP = 500;
    },
        {
        id1 = 123;
        id2 = 345;
        trxDate = May8;
        trxNo = 3455;
        trxP = 530;
    }
)
```